# Matching everything before the last colon

Tags: regex

I have a list of items that looks similar to-

```
AFCNA Gifts:Bags:Duffel Bag
ALPACA CASH
Cash
2000  Discount Farm Day Ad
Estate Items:1 lb Cones of Yarn
AFCNA MFG:Yarn:AFCNA (New) Sock Yarn -Wigwam
WIP CONE YARN:115 White Suri Shawl Yarn
Estate Items:12 lb Alpaca Yarn Hth DkBr
WIP CONE YARN:New Shawl Yarn
```

I need to grab only the item name AFTER the very last colon. Everything before the last colon is unnecessary meta information. I also need it to NOT match any strings that do not contain a colon at all.

So far, I have `^[^:]+\:` but this is grabbing the lines `ALPACA CASH` as well as `Cash`, which do not need to be found.

How can I only grab everything before the very last colon, but only if the line contains a colon at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
[^:]*$
```

to grab text after the last colon.

If you want to grab only from lines where `:` is present then use:

```
:([^:]*)$
```

And you text will be in captured group #1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the regex:

```
:([^:\r\n]+)$
```

And make sure you have the multiline option active so that `$` matches every end of line and not just the end of the whole string.

`:` will match the last `:` in any line (`[^:\r\n]+` makes sure it's the last)

`[^:\r\n]+` matches all the characters that are not `:` or `\r` or `\n` so that you can never match multiple lines.

`([^:\r\n]+)` will be your first capture group and contain the text you're looking for.

`$` matches the end of the line.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kY1yW3).

If you're using a regex engine that supports lookbehinds, you might also try:

```
(?<=:)[^:\r\n]+$
```

Which doesn't require capturing. `(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind and ensures there's a `:`, in this case, before the matched group.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aU1lS0)